# Fourier transform of the raised cosine pulse.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How do I solve for the Fourier transform of the raised cosine function given below:

$$p(t) = \frac{\operatorname{sinc}(Rt)\cos(πaRt)}{1-4a^2R^2t^2},$$
where  $0<a<1$.

P.S.- The final result is known to me but I don't know how to solve for it.

Comment: Section 1 of this paper may help you (although it goes the other way): https://www.michael-joost.de/rrcfilter.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\on{p}\pars{t} & \equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\on{sinc}\pars{Rt}
\cos\pars{\pi aRt} \over 1 - 4a^{2}R^{2}t^{2}}
\end{align}
Lets $\ds{\pars{~\tau \equiv \pi\verts{aR}t \implies t = {\tau \over \pi\verts{aR}}~}}$ and $\ds{\beta \equiv {1 \over \pi\verts{a}}}$ such that
\begin{align}
\on{p}\pars{t} & \equiv
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta t}
\cos\pars{\tau} \over 1 - 4\tau^{2}/\pi^{2}} =
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau}
\cos\pars{\tau} \over \tau^{2} - \pars{\pi/2}^{2}}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,5px]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\on{p}\pars{t}\expo{-\ic\omega t}\,\dd t}
\\ = &\
-\,{\pi^{2} \over 4\pi\verts{aR}}\
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau}
\cos\pars{\tau} \over \tau^{2} - \pars{\pi/2}^{2}}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau}
^{\ds{\equiv {\cal J}}}
\\[2mm] &\
\mbox{where}\quad \nu \equiv {\omega \over \pi\verts{aR}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
{\cal J} & \equiv
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau}
\cos\pars{\tau} \over \tau^{2} - \pars{\pi/2}^{2}}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau}
\cos\pars{\tau} \over \tau - \pi/2}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[2mm] & -
{1 \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau}
\cos\pars{\tau} \over \tau + \pi/2}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
-{\expo{-\ic\nu\pi/2} \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau + \beta\pi/2}
\sin\pars{\tau} \over \tau}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[2mm] &
-{\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2} \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau - \beta\pi/2}
\sin\pars{\tau} \over \tau}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
-{\expo{-\ic\nu\pi/2} \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau + \beta\pi/2}
\on{sinc}\pars{\tau}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[2mm] &
-{\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2} \over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau + \beta\pi/2}
\on{sinc}\pars{\tau}
\,\expo{\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
-{2 \over \pi}\Re\bracks{\expo{-\ic\nu\pi/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau + \beta\pi/2}
\on{sinc}\pars{\tau}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\on{sinc}\pars{\beta\tau + \beta\pi/2}
\on{sinc}\pars{\tau}
\,\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k\pars{\beta\tau + \beta\pi/2}}\,\,\dd k}
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\ic q\tau}
\,\dd q}
\expo{-\ic\nu\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k\beta\pi/2}
\int_{-1}^{1}\
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{\ic\pars{k\beta - q - \nu}\tau}\,\,
{\dd\tau \over 2\pi}}
^{\ds{\delta\pars{k\beta - q - \nu}}}\
\dd q\,\dd k
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k\beta\pi/2}\
\bracks{-1 < k\beta - \nu < 1}\,\dd k
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k\beta\pi/2}\
\bracks{{\nu - 1 \over \beta} < k <
{1 + \nu \over \beta}}\,\dd k
\end{align}
Now, you can finishes the job.